# Ea is the term for activation energy, what is the mean of a in this term?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, energy

Our doctor said it is not stand for activation. it stands for something else, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88929/discussion-on-question-by-dagher-ea-is-the-term-for-activation-energy-what-is-t).

Answer (score 1):

The subscript $\mathrm a$ in $E_\mathrm a$ may refer to Arrhenius.
The [IUPAC gold book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/A/A00102.html) states that:

> activation energy (Arrhenius activation energy)
>   An empirical parameter characterizing the exponential temperature dependence of the rate coefficient, $k$, $E_\mathrm a = RT^2 \frac{\mathrm d(\ln k)}{\mathrm dt}$,
>   where $R$ is the gas constant and $T$ the thermodynamic temperature.

Comment: You haven't read any of the comments to the question, have you? :)

Answer (score 1):

any one interested, the answer of our doctor is a stands for apparent or approximation value of activation energy.
thanks for everyone